# Calculate Rate of Change

Tags: calculus, derivatives

One kilogram of Polonium radioisotope $Po_{84}^{218}$ reduces to 500g in 3 seconds.
a) Calculate the rate per second at which Polonium is decomposing. b) Calculate the mass to which 1kg of this radioisotope is reduced in 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the decomposition is exponential(since it is radioactive decomposition), let $N_t = N_0 e^{-\lambda t}$ where $N_t$ is the amount of the radioisotope that is decomposed after $t$ seconds, $N_0$ is the initial amount of the radioisotope and $\lambda$ is a  constant.

It is given that the half-life of the radioisotope is $3$ seconds. Hence $N_3/N_0 = 0.5 = e^{-\lambda 3}$. After taking the natural logarithm of each side and rearranging terms you get:
$$ \lambda =  - \ln (0.5)/3 \approx 0.231$$

The rate of the decomposition can be found by taking the derivative with respect to $t$:

$$\dfrac{d}{dt} N_t = -0.231e^{-0.231t}$$

And, the amount(mass) left after $t = 15$ is $N_{15} = 1000e^{-0.231 \cdot 15} \approx 31.3\ g$ or $0.0313 kg$.